# Why hard-linked texts are linked but images are not? The images act like different files

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, hardlink, mklink

I used `mklink /H 2.txt 1.txt` to create a hard link of `1.txt`. When I changed one file, the other file was changed, too. But when I did the same thing for a PNG image file, the changes were not shared. That is, the change I made to `2.png` was not applied to `1.png`. How is this so? Did I do something wrong?

[image]

---

PS: I suspect that the image editors (Microsoft Paint and Paint.NET) maybe actually delete the original file and create a new file with the same name when I edit the image and press Ctrl+S, unlike Notepad that actually modified the original file.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618) explains why some programs are designed to do this. The answer is about text editors in *nix but the problem is general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in the way that the program that you used did
the update of the file.

If the program just overwrote the contents of the old text file with
the new contents, then the file is the same in the eyes of the
Windows file-system. In this case the hard link is maintained.

If the program created a new file and deleted the original, then the
hard link is undone (most image editors work like that).
Since you updated via the link, the program deleted only the link, so
the original file was not deleted. The new image file does not
participate in any link, so you now have two files,
original and modified.

Answer (score 0):

Run `fsutil file layout` on both files and compare the "File reference number" (the Windows equivalent to the "inode number"). If after saving those numbers are different, then the files are no longer actually hardlinked – you have a *new* file with the same name.